# Adding titles to automated ping script

Tags: batch-file

I have a little script to ping several IP addresses that are located in a text file called `computers.txt`:
[image: computers]

The output currently looks like this:
[image: Ping test results]

I would like to add a description of where the IP addresses are like so:
[image: Desired results]

What would be the best way to do this?

```
@echo off
set fnm=C:\Users\jelliott\Desktop\computers.txt
set lnm=C:\Users\jelliott\Desktop\results.txt

if exist %fnm% goto Label1

echo.
echo Cannot find %fnm%
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label1
echo PingTest STARTED on %date% at %time% > %lnm%
echo ================================================= >> %lnm%
echo.
for /f %%i in (%fnm%) do call :Sub %%i
echo.
echo ================================================= >> %lnm%
echo PingTest ENDED on %date% at %time% >> %lnm%
echo ... now exiting
goto :eof

:Sub
echo Testing %1
set state=alive
ping -n 1 %1 | find "TTL="
if errorlevel 1 set state=dead
echo %1 is %state% >> %lnm%
```

Comment: Where does the title information come from?

Comment: It would help if we had some idea where the strings, Diagnostic, Clinic and Registration come from! *(Perhaps the mystery contents of computers.txt)*

Comment: Sorry I didn't think it was important. It is just a list of IP addresses in a text file. The IP addresses are all on there own lines

Comment: It's extremely important. Please add a sample file to your question.

Comment: Okay, the computers file was added

Comment: 1. Please add contents of text files as (properly formatted) text here rather than images, so everyone can easily copy them and do some testing! 2. We still do not know where the titles/names should come from; if you want to reach also people without voodoo skills, you should add this information as well...

Comment: No, but where are you getting the _list of titles_ from?

Comment: Try this script ==> [Multi Ping Tester with colors](http://pastebin.com/zjYwSqUM)

Answer (score 1):

When adding the titles to your computers.txt like this:

```
1.2.3.4 Clinic
12.13.14.15 Registration
78.79.251.123 Somwhere else with spaces
```

You can alter your script a bit:

The for loop gets altered to: `for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (%fnm%) do call :Sub %%i "%%j"`
Tokens specifies what part of the line you want to have. The default delimiters are spaces and new lines. So with this the first token of one line gets saved to `%%i` and the rest of the line (`*`) get saved to `%%j` as j is after i in the alphabet. The `%%j` need to get enclosed in double quotes to have multiple words together as one parameter.

Now change your subfunction to use the second parameter as well:

```
echo Testing %1 %~2
REM Other stuff to ping...
echo %~2: %1 is %state% >> %lnm%
```

The `~` removes the surrounding quotes again.

Example output:

```
PingTest STARTED on 11.01.2017 at  7:48:52,69 
================================================= 
Clinic: 1.2.3.4 is alive
Registration: 12.13.14.15 is dead 
Somwhere else with spaces: 78.79.251.123 is alive
================================================= 
PingTest ENDED on 11.01.2017 at  7:49:04,70
```